# activating network-console in debian-installer remotely

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, installation, debian

I'm trying to install a rack of servers remotely. My preseed seems to hang on the physical servers during the installation, so I tried to activate the network-console of debian-installer as described [here](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/NetworkConsole).
Because my IP addresses are defined static in my dhcp server i skipped a static assignment for the network interfaces, so my preseed-code looks like this:

```
    d-i     preseed/early_command   string  anna-install network-console
    d-i     network-console/password        password test
    d-i     network-console/password-again  password test
    d-i     netcfg/get_nameservers  string
    d-i     netcfg/get_ipaddress    string
    d-i     netcfg/get_netmask      string 255.255.255.0
    d-i     netcfg/get_gateway      string
```

My installation (on a virtual machine for testing purposes) end up in a message saying "Continue installation remotely using SSH."

My question is: Can i simply confirm this message by entering 'continue', using the debian-installer preseed command?

To me it seems a bit odd to confirm a remote access to a machine only with physical access. (of course I know about the security aspects of this confirmation, but it is simply not very handy)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is solved, by simply adding

```
   d-i     network-console/start   select  continue
```

to the preseed file, which causes the debian-installer to select the continue button in the start-template of network-console.
My final preseed snippet looks like this:

```
  d-i     preseed/early_command   string  anna-install network-console
  d-i     network-console/password        password test
  d-i     network-console/password-again  password test
  d-i     network-console/start   select  continue
  d-i     netcfg/get_nameservers  string
  d-i     netcfg/get_ipaddress    string
  d-i     netcfg/get_netmask      string 255.255.255.0
  d-i     netcfg/get_gateway      string
```

and I can login via ssh to my installing machine without taking physical interaction.